# PowerShell & VirtualBox: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument

Tags: powershell, virtualbox

**Running this command from the same directory where the ISO and the scripts are:**

.\CreateVM.ps1 --$ImagePath My.iso --DiskPath C:\Users\badmf\VM

**Code:**

```
# This script creates a Win 10 on VirtualBox

Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]

    [string]$ImagePath,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]

    [string]$DiskPath  

    )

$VMName = 'RTU'

$VBManage = 'C:\Program Files\oracle\VirtualBox\VBManage.exe'

# Destroy the VM if it already exists
Invoke-Expression "& 'DestroyVM.ps1' $VMName"

# Create the VM

$VBManage createvm --name $VMName --basefolder $ImagePath --register --ostype Win10

& $VBManage modifyvm $VMName --memory 8048 --vram 256

& $VBManage createhd --filename $DiskPath --size 80000 --format VMDK

& $VBManage storagectl $VMName --name SATA --add sata

& $VBManage storageattach $VMName --storagectl SATA --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd
 
& $VBManage storageattach $VMName --storagectl SATA --port 1 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium $ImagePath

& $VBManage startvm $VMName
```

**And I get this !@#$%^&*()!!!!:**

A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '--DiskPath'.
At line:1 char:1

- .\V0.ps1 --$ImagePath My.iso --DiskPath C:\Users\ ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [V0.ps1], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,V0.ps1
  ```

Those who say you may not use -- because it's incorrect, are wrong.
From the same modified script:

```
$VMName = "RTU"
$VBManage = 'C:\Program` Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe'


# Destroy the VM if it already exists
$ExistingVMs = Invoke-Expression "$VBManage list vms"
if ([bool]($ExistingVMs -match $VMName)) {
    Invoke-Expression "$vboxmanage`  controlvm` $vmName` poweroff"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    Invoke-Expression "$vboxmanage` 'unregistervm` $vmName` --delete"
}
# Create the RTU VM
Invoke-Expression "$VBManage createvm --name $VMName --basefolder $ImagePath --register --ostype Win10"
```

Those arguments are passed to VirtualBox.

On the other hand, Microsoft is inconsistent by sometimes using /, -, -- and sometimes nothing.

I apologize for my anger, I hope one of you who likes PowerShell helps me out.

Answer (score 2):

From the conceptual [about_Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parameters) help topic:

> The parameters follow the command name and have the following form:
>
> `-<parameter_name> <parameter_value>`
>
> `-<parameter_name>:<parameter_value>`
>
> The **name of the parameter** is **preceded by a hyphen (-)** [...]

This tells you that a parameter declared with parameter variable `$DiskPath`, for instance, must be targeted with 
**`-DiskPath`**, *not `--DiskPath`* - ***one* hyphen, not two**.

If you mistakenly use `--`, the token is considered a *positional argument*, i.e. a parameter *value* rather than a name.

If the target command either doesn't support positional arguments or you've already (possibly mistakenly, as in your case) bound all positional parameters with positional arguments, you'll get the error message you saw for any additional positional arguments for which no (remaining) target parameter is declared.

Comment: Thanks mate, that is one of the trillion things I've tried.

Comment: @Max, this answer addresses your question as asked: it explains the syntax problem with your attempt to pass named arguments to PowerShell commands, causing them to be misinterpreted, and shows you how to pass such arguments correctly. If that doesn't help, there must be additional, unrelated problems, which you should create separate question posts for.

Comment: If over half a million people have asked the same question here, who's fault is it?
I didn't get the answer here, but after programming for 35 years I can only say that I must get out of the microsoft BSOD once and for all, PowerShell is totally dumb. 
I did microsoft programming in the 90's, we were all sure it was about to end forever, but it didn't, that crap is still around!

Comment: @Max, this isn't the place for rants. Speaking from personal experience (I answer a lot of PowerShell questions here), yours is the first question I've ever seen about trying to pass PowerShell parameter names with a `--` prefix, but if half a million people have asked the same question before, as you say, then surely there should be plenty of answers around already - and your question should never have been asked and - now that it has - should be closed as a duplicate.